# Ubuntu Resolution

Tags: display, display-resolution

I got a new (to me) screen that's 10 years old and its HDMI port is not recognized by my PC. The only way for me to output screen is via a VGA port. And it works... almost perfectly. Just need a few tweaks.

Every time I start my pc I get the default resolution, because the tv is not recognised by vga: "Unknown Display". To change it to 1920x1080 I use the following command in terminal:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DVI-1 "1920x1080_60.00"
```

Two questions:

1. The screen is shifted by ~20 pixels to the left, is there a variable I can change to shift the screen to the right?
2. Is there a way to automatically change the screen when Ubuntu boots up?

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS  64-bit GNOME 3.28.2
Processor: Intel Core i5-4670 CPU @ 3.40GHz x 4
Graphics: AMD Bonaire

Thank you,
Willie

Comment: I would suggest to use custom xorg.conf, where you could specify your modeline and output. In that way, you can make it default on boot. Try program `cvt` (https://linux.die.net/man/1/cvt) to generate modeline as you have it in your newmode line. About shifting 20 pixels, maybe some different modeline generated with `cvt` would help.

Comment: Dear nobody, I can find a lot about creating custom Xorg files using nvidia, however I can't seem to find creating Xorg files using AMD. In /usr/share/X11 there is a folder called Xorg.conf.d but when I try: sudo nano /usr/share/X11/Xorg.conf a new file is created.

Comment: I've tried to edit the refresh rate using cvt and enter those values in newmode and addmode, it doesn't shift anything. I've looked at the wiki for cvt (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFree86_Modeline) and the four variables per X and Y aren't explained in depth. I'm not sure which variable I can adjust to shift the screen.

Comment: I think you should not mess with `/usr/share/X11`. You should make a new xorg.conf in `/etc/X11/`. Regarding `cvt`, I thought cvt creates a bit different modeline, than the one you have. I would try different refresh frequencies, if they are supportes by monitor. Maybe one of them would shift a picture? I don't know why it would shift, but it is worth trying.